# Control multiple checkboxes in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, material-ui

I have a dropdown menu with several checkboxes and I'm trying to add onClick event on each of them. But when I check one of the checkboxes, all of them are checked. This is what I've tried to do:

```
const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = React.useState(false);

const isCheckboxChecked = () => {
    setIsChecked(isChecked ? false : true)
}

return menuItems.map((item, index) => (
        <React.Fragment>
            <MenuItem
                value={item.value}
                selected={item.value === value}
                key={index}
            >
                <Checkbox
                    key={index}
                    checked={isChecked}
                    onClick={() => isCheckboxChecked()}
                >
                    <Label>{item.label}</Label>
                </Checkbox>
            </MenuItem>
            {index === 2 || index === 3 ? <hr /> : null}
        </React.Fragment>
    ));
```

As I understand, all checkboxes are using the same state `isChecked` and I'm wondering how to make them independent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an array of checked values inside the `isChecked` state variable instead of just one boolean. Your `isCheckboxChecked` method, which I have renamed to the more appropriate name `toggleCheckboxValue`, now takes an `index` argument to target and toggle the corresponding checkbox value.

The `isChecked` value is now filled using the `menuItems` array, each checkbox takes an element from the created array, and finally, you need to pass `index` to the `onClick` event handler of the checkbox.

```
const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = React.useState(menuItems.slice().fill(false));

const toggleCheckboxValue = (index) => {
    setIsChecked(isChecked.map((v, i) => (i === index ? !v : v)));
}

return menuItems.map((item, index) => (
    <React.Fragment>
        <MenuItem value={item.value} selected={item.value === value} key={index}>
            <Checkbox key={index} checked={isChecked[index]}
                      onClick={() => toggleCheckboxValue(index)}>
                <Label>{item.label}</Label>
            </Checkbox>
        </MenuItem>
        {index === 2 || index === 3 ? <hr /> : null}
    </React.Fragment>
));
```

***Note:*** if the length of your `menuItems` array changes dynamically, you'll have to update `isChecked` and `toggleCheckboxValue` accordingly.

Comment: You should not use `useState` hook to handle non-primitive type. Use `useReducer` hook instead.

Comment: "should not" is a bit strong but you're probably right, not because of the non-primitive structure, but more because of the state depending on its previous value. I still believe `useState` is fine here for a simple array of booleans, and I did not want to impose a new hook on the OP.

Comment: @PasVV please post an answer with `useReducer` to allow the OP to choose.

Comment: I'm sorry if it sounds rude. I just tried to remind that thing. :) I can agree your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You should store checkbox index in state and decide checked property of checkbox according to this index.

```
const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = React.useState();

const isCheckboxChecked = (index) => {
    setIsChecked(index)
}

return menuItems.map((item, index) => (
        <React.Fragment>
            <MenuItem
                value={item.value}
                selected={item.value === value}
                key={index}
            >
                <Checkbox
                    key={index}
                    checked={isChecked==index}
                    onClick={() => isCheckboxChecked(index)}
                >
                    <Label>{item.label}</Label>
                </Checkbox>
            </MenuItem>
            {index === 2 || index === 3 ? <hr /> : null}
        </React.Fragment>
    ));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this works like radio buttons, and I want them to work independently.